# Calling javascript function from js file does not works

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript function on my page that works well, but I decided to move it away from index.html to a seperate js file.
The problem is that I cannot get it to execute from that seperate file.

This has been asked many many times here and the solution is always the same, but it just wont work for me. Also on google I can find lots of examples but they simply do not work for me. I tried many of them but with no luck.
So I must be missing something obvious I guess.

This is the header of my index.html

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="gttJSFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
```

The function in gttJSFunctions.js is called Logout()
As I said it works perfect when I put it inside my index.html, but I cant get it to execute from the seperate js file

this is the entire content of gttJSFunctions.js

```
<script language='JavaScript'>

    function Logout()
    {
        conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");
        if (conf)
        {
            window.open("logout.php", "_self");
        }
    }
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't add `<script language='JavaScript'>` inside your script file.

Comment: ^^ That.  Included script files should just be the script - without any script tags

Comment: Is your `gttJSFunctions.js` is in the same folder than your `index.html`?

Comment: OK it was so simple thank you

Comment: @Ivar if you put that in an answer i can accept it because that was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external JavaScript file should contain only JavaScript. No tags.

Just remove the `<script language='JavaScript'>` from your file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<script language='JavaScript'>` from your `gttJSFunctions.js` file because it's already a Javascript file, you don't have to specify it.

**Best practice:** put `<script ... />` tags at the bottom of your code, just before the `</body>` tag. It will improve your page speed and also, as Archer told, avoid you to deal with the DOM ready common mistake.

Comment: Putting at the end of the body also means there's no need for the most common mistake to be dealt with - DOM ready!